# How to move object with arrow keys using document.onkeydown?

Tags: javascript, canvas, event-handling, keyboard-events, onkeydown

I have a task in school where we're supposed to create a moveable object inside a canvas, using arrow keys. I'm having troubles completing the code and making the object actually move. As of now, I only get an alert-box showing the text "undefined" when trying to move the object using right arrow key (as this key is the only one I've started with at the moment). Does anyone have some clue on how to finish up this code? I would be super grateful!

```
window.onload = function(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var x = 0;
var y = 0;

context.fillStyle = "#c409a3";
context.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);
}

document.onkeydown = function(e){
alert(e.keycode);
var rect = new Object();
rect.x = 0;
rect.y = 0;
rect.moveright = function(){rect.x++;}
rect.draw = function(){
   context.fillStyle = "#c409a3";
   context.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, 100, 100)

}
}
rect.erease = function(){
}
rect.moveleft = function(){rect.x--;}

rect.moveup = function(){rect.y++;}

rect.movedown = function(){rect.y--;}


if (e.keyCode == "39"){
    rect.erease();
    rect.moveright();
    rect.draw();
}
if (e.keyCode == "37"){
   rect.erease();
   rect.moveleft();
   rect.draw();
}
if (e.keyCode == "38"){
   rect.erease();
   rect.moveup();
   rect.draw();
}
if (e.keyCode == "40"){
   rect.erease();
   rect.movedown();
   rect.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is homework, you're not going to get a complete solution. But you need to think about (at least):

- When your Rectangle object should be instantiated
- The Scope of all your objects
- Which objects should be in charge of drawing, clearing, movement etc. respectively
- Html Canvas's 2D coordinate system. Which way is up/down and left/right
- If your rectangle may go off the canvas

Apart from that, look at the event API. The property keyCode is in *camel case* and not lowercase.

```
alert(e.keyCode); // camel case
```

That will solve the `undefined` problem